# INSERT INTO sql server error - invalid object name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know I'm doing something daft, so apologies - why do I get an 'Invalid object name PositionsDescription' error for the following SQL statement?

```
with cte as (
        select
            T.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Description
        from @TheRole.nodes('/descriptions/description') as T(C)
    )
    insert into PositionDescriptions (Description)
    select c.Description
    from cte as c
    where not exists (select * from PositionDescriptions as p where p.Description = c.Description)
```

Comment: Is `PositionDescriptions` a table in your database?

Comment: The string `PositionsDescription` appears in your question text but NOT in the quoted code - where's the typo, in this question or in the code?

Comment: Yes it is - I access it in other SPs so I'm a bit confused

Comment: Probably just a typo. Think you confused `PositionDescriptions` with `PositionDescription` or vice versa. Or maybe you are not using the correct connection string and that is why the table is not found?

Answer (score 0):

You are confused between `PositioinsDescription` and `PositionDescriptions`, similar but different.